# After logging in identity interface is null Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to integrate Yii2 login with my custom database. It logs in successfully even session is getting created but identity interface value return empty.

When I try to access Yii::$app->user->identity->username I dont get anything in return.

Have attached the screen shot for reference
[image]

```
Users.php(model)
 <?php
 
 namespace app\models;
 
 use Yii;
 
 /**
  * This is the model class for table "users".
  *
  * @property int $id
  * @property string $username
  * @property string $password
  * @property string|null $created_date
  * @property string|null $update_date
  * @property int|null $is_active
  */
 class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord  implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
 {
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return 'users';
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function rules()
     {
         return [
             [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
             [['created_date', 'update_date'], 'safe'],
             [['is_active'], 'integer'],
             [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
             [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
         ];
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function attributeLabels()
     {
         return [
             'id' => 'ID',
             'username' => 'Username',
             'password' => 'Password',
             'created_date' => 'Created Date',
             'update_date' => 'Update Date',
             'is_active' => 'Is Active',
         ];
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public static function findIdentity($id)
     {
         //return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
      //   $customer = Users::findOne(['id' => $id]);
        // ->where(['id' => $id])
        // ->one();
 
        return new static (Users::findOne(['id' => $id]));
      
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
     {
        /* foreach (self::$users as $user) {
             if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                 return new static($user);
             }
         }
 
         return null;
 
         $customer = Users::find()
         ->where(['to' => $username])
         ->one();*/
     }
 
     /**
      * Finds user by username
      *
      * @param string $username
      * @return static|null
      */
     public static function findByUsername($username)
     {
         $customer = Users::findOne(['username' => $username]);
             //->where(['username' => $username])
             //->one();
         /*foreach (self::$users as $user) {
             if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                 return new static($user);
             }
         }*/
         if($customer=='' || $customer==null){
             return null;
         }else{
             return $customer;
         }
 
         //return null;
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function getId()
     {
         return null;
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function getAuthKey()
     {
         //return $this->authKey;
         return null;
     }
 
     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
     {
         return $this->authKey === $authKey;
     }
 
     /**
      * Validates password
      *
      * @param string $password password to validate
      * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
      */
     public function validatePassword($password)
     {
     //     echo $this->password;
     //     echo $password;
     //     Yii::trace('trace log message');
     //   //  exit;
     $customer = Users::findOne(['password' => $password]);
             //->where(['password' => $password])
             //->one();
         return $customer->password === $password;
     }
 }
```

LoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property-read User|null $user
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        Yii::trace("validating user");
        if ($this->validate()) {
           // echo "hi";
           Yii::trace(print_r($this->getUser(),1));
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = Users::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all in your User model you don't have to check `null` on `findOne`. It retuns `null` if no record found or an example of an entity, so just remove un-necessary code first.